# Augmenting the short documentation of a system function: possible?

Tags: front-end, documentation, internals

A concrete example:

The short documentation for `Fold` (when hovering over the function) refers to `FoldList` without showing the syntax for the order of the arguments of the function. Hence one has to search for `FoldList` and then come back to `Fold` each time one forgets the syntax. There are maybe other examples.

If a manual rewrite of the short documentation is too much can one set up a permanent tooltip that is toggled by a keyboard shortcut for example ?